# Pandas dataframe grouping function to compute date difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
id_a | date

12   | 2020-01-01
12   | 2020-01-02
13   | 2020-01-01
13   | 2020-01-03
14   | 2020-01-01
14   | 2020-01-02
14   | 2020-01-06
```

I would like to be able to make the diff between the max date and min date of each group based on id_a
To get something like

```
id_a | date       | diff

12   | 2020-01-01 | 1
12   | 2020-01-02 | 1
13   | 2020-01-01 | 2
13   | 2020-01-03 | 2
14   | 2020-01-01 | 5
14   | 2020-01-02 | 5
14   | 2020-01-06 | 5
```

I'm trying to do so with something like that:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('id_a').apply(lambda x: max(x['date']) - min(x['date']))
```

But I struggle a bit

Am I on the right path?

Comment: To be able to answer this question, we need to convert `date` to date format, but these dates have an invalid format, what year are they? Which value is the day and which on the month?

Comment: @Erfan format is YYYY-MM-dd

Comment: Your approach is valid, only thing is that you dont want to aggregate the rows, but to keep the same shape of your dataframe, that's why we need `transform` instead of `apply`: `df.groupby('id_a')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `transform` instead of `apply`. Also `np.ptp` would do:

```
 # convert to datetime, ignore if already is
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

 df['date_diff'] = df.groupby('id_a')['date'].transform(np.ptp)
```

Output:

```
   id_a       date date_diff
0    12 2020-01-01    1 days
1    12 2020-01-02    1 days
2    13 2020-01-01    2 days
3    13 2020-01-03    2 days
4    14 2020-01-01    5 days
5    14 2020-01-02    5 days
6    14 2020-01-06    5 days
```

---

**Update**: if you want to get `max` from `date_a` and `min` from `date_b`:

```
groups = df.groupby('id_a')
min_dates = groups['date_b'].transform('min')
max_dates = groups['date_a'].transform('max')

df['date_diff'] = max_dates - min_dates
```

Comment: Weird, which `numpy` version you on, I tried the same and got: `DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation ptp`

Comment: @Erfan numpy '1.16.4', pandas '1.0.1'. Also, why do you have `DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: @QuangHoangThanks a lot and what if I need to use two different columns? Max date from date_a and min date from date_b ? Is it possible with a transform?

Answer (score 3):

we can use `groupby` and then `map` with `np.timedelta` to get the numerical diff in days.

```
s = df.groupby(["id_a"]).agg(min_date=("date", "min"), max_date=("date", "max"))

df['day_diff'] = df["id_a"].map((s["max_date"] - s["min_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "D"))
```

---

```
print(df)

   id_a       date  day_diff
0    12 2020-01-01   1.0
1    12 2020-01-02   1.0
2    13 2020-01-01   2.0
3    13 2020-01-03   2.0
4    14 2020-01-01   5.0
5    14 2020-01-02   5.0
6    14 2020-01-06   5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try joins. But it may require you to create additional data-frames.

```
df_min = df.groupby('id_a', as_index=False).agg({'date':'min'})
df_max = df.groupby('id_a', as_index=False).agg({'date':'max'})

df2 = pd.merge(df,df_max,on=["id_a"],how="inner")
df2 = pd.merge(df2,df_min,on=["id_a"],how="inner")

df2.columns = ['id_a','date','max_date','min_date']
df2['diff'] = df2['max_date'] - df2['min_date']

df2.head()

   id_a       date   max_date   min_date   diff
0    12 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 1 days
1    12 2020-01-02 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 1 days
2    13 2020-01-01 2020-01-03 2020-01-01 2 days
3    13 2020-01-03 2020-01-03 2020-01-01 2 days
4    14 2020-01-01 2020-01-06 2020-01-01 5 days
```